# How do I tell Entity Framework Function Import that a column returned by a stored procedure is not nullable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have an SQL Server stored procedure that ressembles this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [jp].[GetFoo]
    @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS

SELECT
    CONVERT(BIT, (CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetBar](T.Col2) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) IsGetBarCol2EqualToThree
FROM 
    [dbo].[MyTable] T
WHERE
    T.Col1 = @Guid
```

When I do Function Import / Get Column Information in EF, the inferred type of the column IsGetBarCol2EqualToThree is `Nullable<bool>`. But there is no way this field is going to be null, so I'd like it to be just `bool`. Is there a way to do this that would be persistent upon updating (ie that does not rely on modifying any generated code)?

The SQL Server version is 2005, I'm using Visual Studio 2010SP1 with EF 4, project is compiled against .net 4.0.

Comment: what happens if you do this mod. isnull([dbo].[GetBar](T.Col2), 0)?

Comment: It works, thanks. You can put that as answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make this modification: `isnull([dbo].[GetBar](T.Col2), 0)`

Comment: As additional info, I found out there's a bug in the function import: the ISNULL thing works but you have to remove the column from the SP, import it, add the column back (with the ISNULL change), and then import it back.

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu - yes, certain changes don't get updated by using the update command in the GUI.  You'll find that using stored procedures with EF is a major pain in the butt :(

Comment: @EvrenKuzucuoglu - it's not only sprocs - changes to tables / views (column rename, change of nullability) are not refreshed properly in UI neither.

Comment: For some complex views this workaround is not always successful.

Answer (score 3):

You can create complex type and then modify the Nullable property of the generated field.
Can be useful if you don't want to change your sp.

step by step:

- open your edmx
- open model browser (View->Other Windows->Entity Data Model Browser)
- navigate to the field in your generated complex type (*.emdx->Model->Complex Types->your type->field)
- open properties window (press F4)
- among properties there should be Nullable. You can change it here and it will not be overwritten on the next model update, but if you recreate the complex type you will loose your tweak.

Alternatively you can open edmx as xml and find the same property.

```
<ComplexType Name="...">
          <Property Type="Int32" Name="..." Nullable="true" />
```

ps: I tested it in VS2012, EF 5

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways to fix this issue

1- alter procedure to be isnull ("your expression", 0) then update your model from database and refresh .

2- you can open the class model and change it manually but any update on the model again , you will lost the change .

So my opinion is the first solution is the best.