# Make entity framework interpret stored procedure result set column as bool instead of int?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that runs something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ColorId, 
    ColorName,
    CASE
      WHEN ColorId > 5 THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END AS IsNewColor
FROM 
    Colors 
WHERE 
    ColorId = 5
```

When I import the function and create a complex type, it thinks IsNewColor is an int.

I tried returning 'True' or 'False' but then it thinks it's a string.

I can just change the complex type to bool, but is it possible to write the sql differently or something else that would make "Create New Complex Type" realize it should be a bool?

Comment: did you try making it as a BIT?  are you able to show all your codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `CASE` statement in a cast to set it to a `BIT` type

```
CAST(
   CASE
      WHEN ColorId > 5 THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END
   AS BIT) AS IsNewColor
```

Comment: This worked but it defaulted to nullable. Changed the field property like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19156169/1315626